# Where am I waving to?

Tags: steganography

```
 can  my hands at you, but I never say goodbye. 
You are always cool when with me, even more so when I am high!
If you want  be  too, d missing sentence/word. 
 is just simple riddle so… but now I have to go, be…
```

Hint 0:

> something beyond

Comment: Nice! Simple but clever

Comment: BTW I'm not sure what browser you use but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT39b.png) is what I see, where the different 'fonts' are obvious

Comment: @boboquack I had feeling that I made too hard puzzles, so I changed "to infinity" in text to be more obvious and longer text. My chrome hiding it even in Edit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click edit then you can see that certain words have been erased and replaced by question mark emojis

These can be replaced to complete the paragraph:

> **I** can **wave** my hands at you, but I never say goodbye.
> You are always cool when with me, even more so when I am high!
>  If you want **to** be **in** too, **fin**d missing sentence/word.
> **It** is just simple riddle so… but now I have to go, b**y**e…

The added letters can be joined to give

> I wave to in fin it y

So the final answer is, you wave to

> INFINITY

Also fits the hint of 'something beyond'

Comment: Or, just copy and paste the text in a notepad and see the things.

Comment: @Techidiot that works too but mobile :P

Comment: Kind of hoped ppl won't try edit :)

Comment: I haven't found a location I can edit or paste to that doesn't show it exactly as it is seen live. XD