# How I see things in real

Tags: steganography

I just wanted to show you how I see [my puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52421/18250) in real, because I can't see the hidden message (Except that weird "I"). In fact - I don't know what you see in the picture, but I see Red Panda.

Do you see it too?

[image: My last puzzle and Red Panda]

Hint 0:

> It is already in picture.

Hint 1:

> Solution is not a text or a link to picture, but real picture of red panda. Don't you see that picture of red panda between "My last puzzle" picture and "Hint 0"?

Comment: you see "a Red panda" or you see "Red Panda"?

Comment: @jeyejow … maybe The red panda? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So ...

> **[@Techidiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52471/30633)** found "hidden" numbers which decode to "PNG"; this suggested to me another image riding shotgun with the first one.  Sure enough, there are in fact two PNG images concatenated together in the image file.
> Stripping the first one off to reveal the second, gives this image:
>  [image]

**The Red Panda has been found.**

Answer (score 1):

### Very Very Partial

Clicking on the edit

> Gives the info that the image description is -
>
>  [![My last puzzle and Red Panda][112110103]][112110103]
>
>  Which is - My last puzzle and Red Panda 112110103
>
>  The number 112110103 when treated as 112 110 103 and converted from Decimal to ASCII gives - **Png** which means, there is an Imgur hiding here. It's not MlpRP or MlpaRP. So, just need to figure out the imgur here.

Comment: Correct finding of "hidden clue", but not last sentence. -> added Hint 1.

Comment: @DavidStarkey No, I mean Png is correct and only meaning of it.